# In Java's property name, which name is more correct?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

In Java's property name, which name is more correct ?

1. createDate
2. creationDate
3. createdDate
4. others

Please tell me a better expression, because, I'm Japanese.

Comment: Even native English speakers should ask questions like this more often. :)

Comment: The *correctness* depends on the real date's context. Please try to explain *what kind of date* you want to store or model. All names could make sense.

Comment: @Karl - but of course this is true for any language :) But hey, programmers aren't linguists.

Comment: @Andreas_D I'd challenge that, I don't see a situation where `createDate` makes sense for a property name

Comment: @Sean - *create* has some other meanings, where createDate could make sense ( [see item number 6 and 7 here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/create#Verb) )

Comment: Thank you all! I take "creationDate".

Answer (score 11):

Although English is not my mother tongue too I believe that creationDate is better because it means that this is the date when something was created.

`createDate` is irrelevant because it is command: Hey, man, create date!
`createdDate` is speaking about the date itself and not about the date when something else was created.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

just 'created', it's visible it's date from the type

Comment: I was about to agree with this, but then realized that it wouldn't distinguish very well from a boolean of the same name

Answer (score 2):

I would personally go for `creationDate` if it's a property name. If it's a method which creates a date, `createDate` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the usage. if it is holding some date when something gets created then

`creationDate` would be good

Answer (score 1):

I would like creationDate (= 作成日)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would use all three names:

```
String creationDate = "2011-01-01";
boolean createdDate = createDate(creationDate);
```

(Honestly: I'd rather name the boolean variable `hasCreatedDate` but that's pretty close)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO "creation" is more formal than "created". The first implies an official or planned creation, whereas created is when it actaully happened in the past.

createdDate is past tense and implies this is something which has happened. This is what I would expect to see. e.g. if you look at the properties for a file in Windows, it will give you the date/time for "Created", "Modified" and "Accessed"

creationDate implies a planned date which could be in the future. e.g. factory.setCreationDate("2012-01-01") It could also be the planned or offical creation date but is not the actual date it was created (due to same delay)

createDate is an action which implies you want to create a new date object.

Alternatives might be

- dateCreated();
- dateOfCreation();
- createdOn();

Answer (score 0):

I would go for (and have gone for) "createDate" myself.

Comment: Bad Idea. createDate reads like "Create Date!" That should be a method name, not a field name.

Comment: I don't agree, but i guess its up to taste. creation etc sounds bloated, and a method starts with a cap, right?:)

Comment: No, method names are normally not written starting with a capital letter in Java!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no native too, but personally I would prefer something like `dateOfCreation` to make things totally clear.

Answer (score 0):

createDate - This reflects if we are creating a Date or as already mentioned by someone it sounds more like a method name. So this should be discarded.

creationDate - This appears to me as an appropriate one. It is clearly reflecting the date on which a particular thing is created.

createdDate - This could also be used, but I would suggest use it in a different format like 
createdOn or createdBy

Comment: "creationDate - ... the date ... a ... thing is created." You say you prefer creation but use created.

Comment: @Peter- Don't go so strict word by word. I meant use creation